# Blobs and Files retrieved from Indexeddb on IOS are empty

Tags: javascript, ios, blob, mobile-safari, indexeddb

I want to store images in IndexedDB, and I am using [Dexie](https://dexie.org/) for it. When I store an image in IndexedDB and retrieve it immediately afterward, I can display the image. However, when I store it, then reload the page, and subsequently retrieve it, I can't display it on iOS devices. It does work for all the Android and Windows devices I have tried.

#### More code context:

Dexie Init config: `_imageDB.version(2).stores({ images: 'id, associatedContent' });`

Store image: `await db.images.add(image);`

Get Image: `db.images.where('associatedContent').equals(associatedContent).toArray();`

An image object looks like this:

```
{
  id: 'f9ce4b59-0219-437a-a749-fde1c75d4dd7',
  name: 'iphonetest.jpg',
  file: new File([blob], 'iphonetest.jpg'),
  associatedContent: 'test',
  creationTime: Date.now(),
  uploadTime: Date.now(),
},
```

#### Tried solutions:

I tried multiple things to display the retrieved data. And as I said all of them work for Windows and Android and none for ios.

I always try to display them with this img tag: `<img src={picture.original} alt={picture.originalAlt} loading='lazy' />`.

I tried:

1. Create a new File from the retrieved data, then creating an object url:

   ```
   const file = new File([cachedImage.file], cachedImage.name)
   picture.original = URL.createObjectURL(file)
   ```
2. Create a new Blob from the retrieved data:

   ```
   const blob = new Blob([cachedImage.file])
   picture.original = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
   ```
3. Create the object url directly from the cached image data:

   ```
   picture.original = URL.createObjectURL(cachedImage.file)
   ```
4. Store the image not as File but as Blob.

So far each try ended with this [blue questionmark box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obWCX.png).

Tries 1 and 2 result in a file/blob with a size of 0. When I check the `cachedImage.file.size` I get the correct 16522.